$\int_{0}^{1}\tan^{-1} \left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right) \: {\rm d}x$
$$\int_{0}^{1}\tan^{-1} \left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right) \; {\rm d}x$$
Initially my idea was to substitute $x \leftarrow \cos(\theta)$ but then that involves dealing with ${\cos(\theta) - 1 \over \cos(\theta)}$ or ${2 \sin^2(\theta/2) \over \cos(\theta)}$ and I am unsure how to proceed. The reasoning behind the substitution was the identity $$\tan(\theta/2) = {\cos(\theta) - 1 \over - \sin(\theta)}$$ Is there a better way to do this?

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=+Integrate%5Barctan%5C%2840%291-Divide%5B1%2Cx%5D%5C%2841%29%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C1%7D%5D

Why downvote for just asking a question?

First of all, let $u=1-x$:
$$\int_0^1 \tan^{-1}\left(1-\frac1x\right)\mathrm dx=\int_0^1 \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x-1}x\right)\mathrm dx=\int_0^1 \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{u}{u-1}\right)\mathrm du $$
Now, using $\tan^{-1}(y)+\tan^{-1}(1/y)=-\pi/2$ for $y<0$, you get:
$$\int_0^1 \tan^{-1}\left(1-\frac1x\right)\mathrm dx =\frac12 \int_0^1 \left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x-1}x\right)+ \tan^{-1}\left(\frac x{x-1}\right)\right)\mathrm  dx=-\frac{\pi} 4 $$

Integration by parts is not difficult.
$$I=\int \tan ^{-1}\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)\,dx=x \tan ^{-1}\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)-\int \frac{x}{2 x^2-2 x+1}\,dx$$
$$\frac{x}{2 x^2-2 x+1}=\frac 12 \frac x{(x-a)(x-b)}$$ where $(a,b)=\frac {1\pm i}2$. Using partial fraction decomposition
$$\int \frac{x}{2 x^2-2 x+1}\,dx =\frac 1{2(a-b)}\int \Big(\frac a{x-a}-\frac b{x-b}  \Big)\,dx$$

$\int_0^1\tan^{-1}(1-\frac1x)dx=\int_0^1\tan^{-1}(\frac{x-1}{x})dx$
$y=\frac{x-1}x, dy=\frac{dx}{x^2}$
$\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{\tan^{-1}(y)}{(y-1)^2}dy$
We can do a $u$ substitution: $u=tan^{-1}(y), dv=\frac{dy}{(y-1)^2}$
resulting in: $\frac{\tan^{-1}(y)}{y-1}-\int\frac{dy}{(y-1)(y^2+1)}$
We can do partial fraction decomposition to simplify the integrand to $(-\frac{1}{2(v^2+1)}-\frac{v}{2(v^2+1)}+\frac{1}{2(v-1)})dv$
The first integral is solved with trigonometric-substitution. Second integral solved with u-substitution of $u=v^2+1$ and 3rd is just equivalent up to linear factors to the integral of $\frac1x$. I need to go so i won't finish the whole thing but i told you how so you can figure it yourself.
